# Assembly 16BIT NewLine

Tags: assembly, newline

Hi I'm making a simple Hello World Program in Assembly.
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]

```
  MOV SI, HelloString
  CALL PrintString

  MOV SI, NewLine
  CALL PrintString
  ;New line here
  MOV SI, HelloString2
  CALL PrintString
  JMP $

  ;Write String Method {
  PrintCharacter:
  MOV AH, 0x0E
  MOV BH, 0x00
  MOV BL, 0x07
  INT 0x10
  RET
  PrintString:
  next_character:
  MOV AL, [SI]
  INC SI
  OR AL, AL
  JZ exit_function
  CALL PrintCharacter
  JMP next_character
  exit_function:
  RET
  ;} Write String Method    


  HelloString db 'Hello World', 0
  HelloString2 db 'Hi, my name is Ottovolante321', 0

  times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
  dw 0xAA55
```

How can I include a NewLine between the Two String?
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Can you add a '\n' character to the 1st line ?

Comment: Don't Work. I tryed it yet

Answer (score 0):

```
HelloString db 'Hello World'
            db 13,10,0
HelloString2 db 'Hi, my name is Ottovolante321'
            db 13,10,0
```

Simply insert the carriage return, line feed characters before the end-of-string indicator.

Comment: After making the changes above, remove the `MOV SI, NewLine; CALL PrintString` lines from your code as they're no longer necessarily. If that still doesn't work describe exactly how it doesn't work.